# loadermax to get qualified class name of the swf

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

The typical as3 code would be like this

```
private function load():void {
        var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);

        if(Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE) {
            loaderContext.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
        }

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, handleInit);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("capture.swf"), loaderContext);
    }

    private function handleInit(event:Event){
        var className:String = getQualifiedClassName(loader.content);
        var classRef:Class = loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(className) as Class;
        var captureModule = new classRef();
        addChild(captureModule as DisplayObject);
    }
```

now while using greensock's loadermax, how can I access the qualified class name, it's reference, create an object myself and add to display.

```
loaderMax.append(new SWFLoader("capture.swf", {name:"capture"}));
loaderMax.append(new SWFLoader("filter.swf", {name:"filter"}));
loaderMax.load();
```

the loadComplete function

```
        function completeHandler(event:LoaderEvent): void {
            trace(event.target + " is complete");
            var capture = loaderMax.getContent("capture");
            trace(getQualifiedClassName(capture)); //want to reach the custom class of the loaded sf
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that the loaded swf has a property loaderInfo.loader that you can access to use the loader.

```
var loader = loaderMax.getContent("capture").rawContent.loaderInfo.loader;
this.data["capture"] = loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(getQualifiedClassName(loaderMax.getContent("capture").rawContent)) as Class;
```